# Как добавить динамическую подгрузку элементов страницы?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Как добавить динамическую подгрузку элементов страницы?

При выборе radio red должны ниже появиться новые color2 элементы. При выборе других - другие:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="color2" value="red">светло красный<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color2" value="r2"> красный<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color2" value="r3"> тёмно красный
</form>
```

.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> красный<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> синий<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> зеленый
</form>

<label id="Name2">Name2</label>

<script>
    $('input:radio[name="color"]').change(
    function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            if (($(this).val()) == "red")
            {
                $("#Name").html($(this).val());
                //здесь доллно произой появление новых элементов.
            }
            else { $("#Name").html("Name") };

        }
        //if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
        //    $("#Name").html( $(this).val() );
        //}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Сделай скрипт который будет получать на входе параметры, а на выходе элементы которые должны подгрузиться в формате JSON.
После чего делай ajax-запрос на этот скрипт и выводи в на страницу в какой-нибудь блок. Все просто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input:radio[name="color"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {


    var color = $(this).val();
    
    //скрываем остальные блоки
    $('#hiddenforms>div').hide();
    
    //показываем блок с нужным цветом
    $('#' + color).show();
    
    //сбрасываем нажатое на скрытых блоках
    $('#hiddenforms>div:hidden input:radio[name="color2"]:checked').prop('checked', false);
    
  }
});
```

```css
#hiddenforms>div {
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> красный<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> синий<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> зеленый


  <div id="hiddenforms">

    <div id="red">
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="red1">светло-красный<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="red2">красный<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="red3">темно-красный
    </div>

    <div id="blue">
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="blue1">светло-синий<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="blue2">синий<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="blue3">темно-синий
    </div>

    <div id="green">
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="green1">светло-зеленый<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="green2">зеленый<br>
      <input type="radio" name="color2" value="green3">темно-зеленый
    </div>


  </div>

</form>
```